# htaccess multipurpose rewrite rules conflict

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have 2 simple PHP files:

```
product.php
product-options.php
```

And in my htaccess file i have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product$ product.php [L]
RewriteRule ^options$ product-options.php [L]
RewriteRule ^product-([^/]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^options-([^/]+)/?$ product-options.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Everything works fine when i call "**mysite.com/product**" or "**mysite.com/product-MYID**"

But when i call "**mysite.com/options**" or "**mysite.com/option-MYID**" i see the correct url but the content of the file is "product" / "product-MYID" !!! Why???

PS: i need that both files are accessibile with and without the GET ?id=ID

Comment: It's just because you redirect -> options -> product-options.php... -> product-... -> product.php...

Comment: The easier for you is to change `product-options.php` to `options.php` or to put `.php` file in a folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product$ product.php [L]
RewriteRule ^options$ product-options.php [L]
RewriteRule ^product-([^/\.]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^options-([^/\.]+)/?$ product-options.php?id=$1 [L]
```

because, I think, you don't use . in your product-... or option-...

Answer (score 1):

That is because your rules are executing 2nd time as regex is:

```
^product-([^/]+)/?$
```

Which matches `/product-MYID` URI as well as rewritten URI: `product-options.php`

In order to avoid this you can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is for a valid directory or file then skip rewrite rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^product/?$ product.php [L]
RewriteRule ^options/?$ product-options.php [L]
RewriteRule ^product-([^/]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^options-([^/]+)/?$ product-options.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```